# Phpmailer and sendmail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have this error when I try to send an E mail.
I use the latest phpmailer.

```
Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f

" object(PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer)#42 (75) { ["Priority"]=> NULL ["CharSet"]=> string(5) "utf-8" ["ContentType"]=> string(10) "text/plain" ["Encoding"]=> string(16) "quoted-printable" ["ErrorInfo"]=> string(73) "Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f
```

until now it works fine, but no possible to send email with this problem.

Not sure, but I think some hoster insert a restriction, Do you have any idea to change that ?
Use the SMTP ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use PHP's `mail()` function (what PHPMailer uses by default), it opens a shell and calls a sendmail binary (a client program for submitting email messages from a command line) belonging to your local mail server. If you don't have a local mail server, it can't work, and you get the error you're seeing. You could get the same error if there is a mail server, but you don't have permission to run sendmail.

You need to do one of:

1. Install a mail server (such as postfix)
2. Talk to a local server via
   SMTP (which will not be subject to permissions issues in the same
   way that `mail()` is)
3. Use SMTP to send through a remote mail server,
   either your ISP's or some other server such as gmail (if your ISP
   allows outbound SMTP).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your explanation. I have postfix installed, inside my panel I created my own email. It not work, try to send in sendmail, smtp via tls (587) or ssl 465 not work. Only gmail in ssl and 465 work correctly. Try with Free.fr not work.